# Размер текста внутри кнопки

Tags: html, css

Есть кнопка

```
<input type="button" class="ok" value=" ОДНОКЛАССНИКИ ">
```

Стиль для нее

```
.ok{
    background: #df922f;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    color: #ffffff;
    border:0;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 5px; 
    width: 16%;
    height: 5%;
    font-size:100%;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:2%;
    right:37%;

}
```

Как сделать чтобы текст внутри этой кнопки масштабировался вместе с кнопкой?

Comment: Можете задавать размер текста в единицах `vw`. Например: `font-size:1.4vw;`. Но учтите, что на мобильных устройствах текст может быть слишком мелким, а на больших экранах - слишком большим.

Comment: @Pyramidhead Спасибо, помогло!

Comment: @Pyramidhead Создайте ответ на основе комментария, раз автору вопроса это помогло.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете задавать размер текста в единицах `vw` *(1vw = 1% от ширины окна)*. Например: `font-size:1.4vw;`.

Но учтите, что на мобильных устройствах текст может быть слишком мелким, а на больших экранах - слишком большим.